# Colormap a 3D curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have 4 arrays `x`, `y`, `z` and `T` of length `n` and I want to plot a 3D curve using `matplotlib`. The `(x, y, z)` are the points positions and `T` is the value of each point (which is plotted as color), like the temperature of each point. How can I do it?

**Example code:**

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
n = 100
cmap = plt.get_cmap("bwr")
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, n)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
T = (2*np.random.rand(n) - 1)  # All the values are in [-1, 1]
```

What I found over the internet:

- It's possible to use `cmap` with `scatter` like shown in the docs and in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991355/matplotlib-3d-plot-use-colormap)

```py
ax = plt.gca()
ax.scatter(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, c=T)
```

The problem is that `scatter` is a set of points, not a curve.

- In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810274/python-colormap-in-matplotlib-for-3d-line-plot) the solution was divide in `n-1` intervals and each interval we use a different color like

```py
t = (T - np.min(T))/(np.max(T)-np.min(T))  # Normalize
for i in range(n-1):
    plt.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], z[i:i+2], c=cmap(t[i])
```

The problem is that each segment has only one color, but it should be an gradient. The last value is not even used.

**Useful links:**

- [Matplotlib - Colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)
- [Matplotlib - Tutorial 3D](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Comment: What's the problem with the first solution with scatter and cmap? Isn't that exactly what you want ?

Comment: The ```scatter``` is not a curve

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you probably need to use `Line3DCollection`. This is the recipe:

1. create segments from your array of coordinates.
2. create a `Line3DCollection` object.
3. add that collection to the axis.
4. set the axis limits.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Line3DCollection
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

def get_segments(x, y, z):
    """Convert lists of coordinates to a list of segments to be used
    with Matplotlib's Line3DCollection.
    """
    points = np.ma.array((x, y, z)).T.reshape(-1, 1, 3)
    return np.ma.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
n = 100
cmap = plt.get_cmap("bwr")
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, n)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
T = np.cos(theta)

segments = get_segments(x, y, z)
c = Line3DCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, array=T)
ax.add_collection(c)
fig.colorbar(c)

ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
ax.set_zlim(z.min(), z.max())
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tested and this solution is the same as the second one. The difference is: this one is faster cause we don't call ```plt.plot``` many times. With a small value of ```n``` or when ```T``` is very random, we still see the color segments.